# Can we convert any parametric equation to implicit form?

Tags: parametric-functions, implicit

The Archimedes spiral equation in parametric form:

```
fx[t_] := Cos[t]*t;
fy[t_] := Sin[t]*t;
```

How can it be converted to implicit form?

Is there a general method to convert any parametric equation to implicit form?

Comment: The spiral of Archimedes can indeed be expressed as an implicit Cartesian equation, but it isn't pretty or more useful than the parametric or polar one: `x Tan[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] == y`

Comment: @J.M.willbebacksoon I included the spiral of Archimedes for possible input. The solutions to this issue that I found here could not cope with this curve.

Comment: In principle, if the components of the parametric equations only have trigonometric functions of the parameter, one can derive an implicit Cartesian equation (e.g. [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/203169)). Otherwise, there isn't any general method that would work on e.g. `{x == Exp[t] + t^2, y == t - Cos[t]}`.

Comment: @J.M.willbebacksoon "Otherwise, there isn't any general method that would work" How is it prove in mathematics?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
fx[t_] := Cos[t]*t;
fy[t_] := Sin[t]*t;

ParametricPlot[{fx[t], fy[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

```
sol = Assuming[Element[{x, y}, Reals],
  Eliminate[{x == fx[t], y == fy[t]}, t,
    InverseFunctions -> True] //
   FullSimplify]

t^2 == x^2 + y^2 && x == t Cos[t]
```

Since `t` was not eliminated

```
solxy = sol[[-1]] /. Solve[sol[[1]], t, Reals] // FullSimplify

(* {x + Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] Cos[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] == 0, 
 x == Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] Cos[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]} *)
```

The result is the original spiral and its mirror

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate@solxy,
 {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]