# Get curve equation from parametrization

Tags: equation-solving, parametric-functions

I am quite new to Mathematica and I have been wondering how to do this one very specific thing.

I have two functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ that are the parametrization of a curve, how would I get the equation $E(a,b)=0$ that describes the curve?

My thought process is to solve for $t$ in terms of $x(t)$ and then substitute in $y(t)$.
How would I automatize this in Mathematica?

Comment: Read this: [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/209696/can-we-convert-any-parametric-equation-to-implicit-form)